# Why can you skip using the `new` keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor, specifications

#### Premise:

So whether you construct from a `function` or `es6 class` or `base class` you are supposed to initialize like (*for now let's ignore short-hand constructors*):

```
const Fruit = function(name) {this.name = name}
class Ball {
  constructor(color) {this.color = color}
}

const apple = new Fruit('apple')
const red_ball = new Ball('red')
const ob = new Object()
const arr = new Array()
```

#### Confusion:

But here's the thing, if I killed the `new` keyword above in all statements:

- `Class`

  > Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor A cannot be invoked without 'new'
- `Function` (*Es5 class*)

  > `Undefined`
- `Array / Base Classes` - ***It initialized correctly! but Why?***

  > `[]` or `{}`

#### Thoughts:

It could be a really stupid question, but I cannot find any references as to why that's the case, but this behavior seems to unanimously apply in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Node.js

Comment: To be a bit more explicit than the dupe, in the case of `Array()` vs `new Array()`, it's [because the spec says so](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-objects): _" When Array is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it also creates and initializes a new Array object. Thus the function call Array(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Array(…) with the same arguments."_ `Object` is along the same lines - the spec defines what happens.

Comment: `Fruit` is a function, but does not return anything, hence `undefined`
similarly, `Array` and `Object` are also functions, but they return array/object respectively. You'r `Ball` Class however, is a special kind of function that cannot be instantiated without the `new` keywork

Comment: @JamesThorpe Just what I was looking for! Thanks!